# Is there a way to call a executable file in another folder?

Tags: python, ros

I'm new in ros and python and I'm wondering if there's a way to call a executable file when I am in another folder. 
In other words, I have a ros node called A (who publish to the node B) and another node called B (who receive data from node A) these two nodes are in the same folder.

I want to call a executable script in my node B to modify this data received but this executable script is located outside my workspace. And I want launch everything with a launch file is that possible? 
Thank you!

Comment: Add the path to where you call the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep all your executables/data in a catkin workspace where ros can find it (ex `roscd my_pkg`, then in your launch file you can find paths to files. Cf. [roslaunch/xml syntax](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML).

```
<param name="path_to_my_exe" value="$(find my_pkg)/bin/my_exe.sh"/>
```

You can also just run the executable, "as a node", from the roslaunch file as well, since all nodes are just called executables.
Or you could just hardcode the path as a parameter or argument, if you want to pass it in via cmd line.

```
<arg name="path_to_my_exe" default="~/catkin_ws/my_pkg/bin/my_exe.sh"/>
<node ...>
  <param name="path_to_my_exe" value="$(arg path_to_my_exe)"/>
</node>
```

Cmd line, argument optional: `roslaunch my_pkg main.launch path_to_my_exe:=~/diff/folder/other_exe.sh`